# Games with known outcome but unknown strategy

Tags: game-theory

> Is there any two-player game for which it is known that a *particular*
>   player (not just one of the two players) has a *winning* strategy but
>   no such strategy is known explicitly?

I see that it might be possible to prove a winning strategy by combining a no-draw game with a strategy-stealing argument, but I cannot find an explicit example where the winning strategy is not immediately obvious.

Bonus points for a **real-world** (rather than just theoretical) game that has this property.

Comment: When you say 'but no such strategy is known explicitly' do you mean it isn't yet known, or it is *unknowable*?

Comment: @DanielRust: I mean to say it isn't known. I'd be very much interested in a game where the optimal strategy is "unknowable", though!

Comment: It appears that the real-world game **Hex** actually [has that property for some board sizes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_(board_game)#Strategy).

Comment: most games have this property (e.g., go, chess (with draws eliminated), north-west corner etc.). Which games do you have in mind where the strategy is obvious?

Comment: @Ittay, which player has a winning strategy for draws-eliminated chess? For that matter, what is draws-eliminated chess?

Comment: @IttayWeiss: I agree with Gerry, even for Go that claim does not seem to be true. While Go allows for strategy-stealing (because passing is allowed), Go certainly allows for a draw as well (and no obvious way to eliminate that possibility) so Go seems to be out.

Comment: I missed the requirement that it is known which player has a winning strategy. Then scratch chess and go, but keep the north-west corner. Even for small board sizes, the winning strategy for the first player is unknown.

Comment: @IttayWeiss: Can you point me to the game "north-west corner"? I can only find a game *publisher* by that name.

Comment: Maybe Ittay is talking about the game known as Chomp (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomp). I think it's a good answer to the question.

Comment: I learned it as the north-west corner (which is how the strategy stealing is done). It is, apparently, Chomp. Thanks Gerry.

Comment: I see... indeed, that game also appears to fall into that category. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: The Gomoku game without additional rules has a bias towards first player, but I don't know if this bias guarantees victory; even if it's the case, I don't know if the winning strategy is known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summing up the remarks above (and using Gerry's link): A classical example of a game where it is known the first player has a winning strategy yet, even for small board sizes, no strategy is known is the game [Chomp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomp).